# Suddenly "Filter failed" message from cups

Tags: printing, cups

I was using a Kyocera TASKalfa 4052ci Printer over the Network without major issues but suddenly I can't print anymore, I get a "Filter Failed" message on the cups site. My error_log says:

```
E [06/Jul/2021:10:40:07 +0200] [cups-driverd] Skipping \"/usr/share/ppd/kyocera\": loop detected!
E [06/Jul/2021:10:40:15 +0200] [CGI] ippfind (PID 584028) stopped with status 2!
W [06/Jul/2021:10:40:17 +0200] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'Kyocera-TASKalfa-4052ci-KPDL-Gray..\' already exists
W [06/Jul/2021:10:40:17 +0200] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'Kyocera-TASKalfa-4052ci-KPDL-CMYK..\' already exists
```

I tried different drivers without success. I tried rolling back cups and cups-filters but nothing changed. Is there anyway I can fix this? Thanks!